# Creating QRcode in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Need to create the QRcode for the for specific URL, so that customer will scan the QR code and redirect to specific URL.

Comment: This will help you https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-create-qr-code-for-magento-product/